# Error in batch script for update a script, can anyone find the error?

Tags: batch-file, batch-updates

I am attempting to make a script that is called from another script to update him...

This script is downloaded from a server via wget and it is started by other script. It checks version of RunToolkit and, if it isn't v1.1, it downloads the new version...

But when this script is called, it give an error, "unexpected goto".

Hers is the script:

```
@echo off
echo Latest version is 1.1

:restart
IF EXIST RunToolkit.exe (
      FIND /I "1.1" "RunToolkit.exe" > NUL:
              IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
              ECHO Your toolkit version is 1.1
              echo No updates available!
              PAUSE
              goto quit
              ) ELSE (
              ECHO Your toolkit is outdated, do you want to update it?
              ECHO.
              ECHO 1. Yes
              ECHO 2. No
              ECHO.
              SET /P menunr=Select number you want :
              IF %menunr%==1 (goto yesupdate)
              IF %menunr%==2 (goto quit)
              goto what
              )
)

:yesupdate
echo Downloading new version!
wget (link deleted for privacy :P)

:what
echo.
echo You entered a wrong number! Retry!
PAUSE
goto restart

:quit
call RunToolkit.exe
```

Can anyone find the error, please?

Comment: @rudu - A trailing colon is optional when redirecting to devices like `nul:` and `con:`. It does not cause a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue, nothing to do with your error is

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
```

Which should alwaays be true. `if errorlevel n` means `if errorlevel is n OR GREATER THAN n`. There **ARE** ways of setting errorlevel negative - but normal operation would always set a positive errorlevel, hence `if errorlevel 0` should always be true.

Your next problem is that CMD always substitutes the `current` value for any `%var%` in any logical line, then validates the line. The logical line here starts at `IF EXIST` and runs through to the single closing-parenthesis in the first column - 18 physical lines later.

At that time, `IF %menunr%==1 (goto yesupdate)` will be evaluated as `IF ==1 (goto yesupdate)` because `menunr` is undefined `WHEN THE LINE WAS PARSED`. This is the source of your `UNEXPECTED GOTO`

Since you are entering `memunr` you need to learn about `delayedexpansion` - here's a demo:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
cls
set var=ORIGINAL
echo Start value of var=%var%
for %%i in (1) do (SET var=AFTER
ECHO var is %var% in the for loop
)
echo Final value of var=%var%
ENDLOCAL
ECHO.
echo ---- try again with ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO. 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var=ORIGINAL
echo Start value of var=%var%
for %%i in (1) do (SET var=AFTER
ECHO var is %var% not !var! in the for loop
ECHO Note: in the loop VAR has old value %var% and new value !var!
)
echo Final value of var=%var%
endlocal
```

Note the difference between `%var%` (the `PARSE-TIME` value) and  `!var!` (the `RUN-TIME` value)

ALSO:

If you press simply `ENTER` as a response to `SET /P menunr=Select number you want :` then `menunr` will remain UNCHANGED. Since it had no value, it will still have no value, and hence if you turn on `delayedexpansion` by mans of a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` statement, the logical change

```
IF %menunr%==1 (goto yesupdate)
```

to
`IF !menunr!==1 (goto yesupdate)`

will also suffer the same error.

You need to use

```
IF "!menunr!"=="1" (goto yesupdate)
```

to cater for the empty-variable scenario.

(also: the parentheses around the `GOTO` here are superfluous, but harmless)

Comment: +1, I was in the midst of preparing basically the same answer, no point now :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the awesome reply! It is super-explained! I solved creating a label and adding after ELSE "goto label". In the label i put the set menunr with the IF... I also modified the IF ERRORLEVEL from 0 to 1. Now it works! ;)